# Which Programming Language or tool should I Use for this project?

Tags: analysis

I have to work on a project which

- runs on a single system ie., single User
- User Will record entries and get reports based on date
- Deployment overhead should be less.

Since i am a web developer, it will be better if you suggest me a web based frameworks like PHP, Python with Django...that suits the above needs.

If the web based idea looks silly please forgive me. Awaiting your responses.

Comment: As usual for "What language should I use?" questions, the answer is either "Whatever you know best" (duplicated many times) or "Whatever the answer's favourite system is" (so very very subjective). Voting to close. (In honour of the latter: My favourite system is Perl + DBIx::Class + Catalyst, although Catalyst is almost certainly overkill for this).

Comment: Why close requests for this question..Any reason?

Comment: @david Dorward, But here my criterias are different

Comment: They aren't different in any significant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are two roads to go here:

Based on the provided information, I'd make sure there isn't something out there that already does what you aim to do. I'd start there.

If you're really determined to do it yourself, or if your needs cannot be fulfilled with an off-the-shelf solution, then the world is your oyster. You can basically build it in any language you want. Of course some solutions are better than others.

If you're really comfortable with WAMP/LAMP servers and PHP/MySql stuff, then you can always run one of those on your home network and build the application like you would any other web app.

You can do C/C++ on basically any platform, although with windows, your mileage will vary.

Managed languages (C#/Java/VB.NET) are good to get going on single system solutions because they tend to take all the hard low-level OS work out of the equation. Java is more capable than C#/VB.NET in cross-platform situations though.

I'd think those through. It's really tough to answer objectively, because the question is begging for personal preference answers. People are VERY fond of the languages and platforms they prefer. I'd do what is easiest and best for you. Unless you're looking for a challenge.